# VPN vs VPS vs TOR vs ANON_PROXY?

Tags: anonymity, tor

Which option is better for anonymity among these 4 choices? When can the ISP or website see you? When can't they?

(There are some articles through google, "VPN and TOR difference" or etc, but I need your answers.)

Comment: This depends on what you are trying to protect yourself from. A vpn provides privacy, tor provides anonimity. But just using tor won't make you anonymous on the web as there are things like browser finger printing etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mix of them but you need to manage risks carefully and thoughtfully.

- VPN protects against sniffing of your ISP, and helps with tracking protection. Use it if you are tracked by someone malicious trough ad networks and ISP
- VPS same as VPN but does not protect from tracking as much as VPN service does. Use it if you are tracked by someone malicious via your ISP.
- TOR protects you from sniffing and tracking if used with Tor Browser. This is extreme option for people targeted by dictatorships.
- Anon proxy helps with tracking and adware as well, it's all round good for paranoid, but it's not good against sophisticated adversaries

Don't forget about DNSCrypt as well.

Basically:

- To get protection from sniffing, use VPN, VPS or TOR for HTTP proxy, so unencrypted traffic won't leave your PC
- You can leave HTTPS proxy settings unchanged
- Install DNSCrypt
- Secure your browser from tracking
- Make 14 random letter long password on WiFi if you use it or use PEAP

Regarding securing your browser, make it clear cookies on every exit except for cookies you need to use, for example, Google only.

In the browser you can disable number of APIs with add-ons which just burn your CPU and battery and are potential vectors for reconnaissance, these include - WebGL (via NoScript), Canvas, Battery, WebRTC, Firefox Resources.

You can also use HTTPS Everywhere to speed up your browsing if you proxy HTTP traffic.

Additionally, you can disable AES-128 in browser so it will use AES-256 or Chacha20-Poly1905 which are both 256 bit strong. Not sure about key exchange yet.

ps. Proxying HTTP traffic trough Tor is very risky as Exit Nodes can add malicious scripts to it. Same for using Tor Browser on day to day basis.

Comment: thanks for such good answer.  Just i dont know: 
1) what's difference between privacy and anonimity.
2) what's difference between "TOR" and "TOR BROWSER"  [3) p.s. thanks for DNScrypt ! ]

Comment: @TazoTodua 1) privacy means that your ISP can't see what websites you visit, while anonimity means that if you upload or download something no one knows who did this.

Comment: @A.Darwin you confused me, now i quite misunderstood them..  please, review my updated question, where I ask the difference like you said.